# Identifying/Coloring-in Lists of Duplicates in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Need some help with the below code. Currently trying to highlight duplicated tracking numbers with the same color, then move on to the next set and use a different color. It keeps getting an error (Error 9, subscript exceeded) or doesn't run.

I have a LOT of tracking numbers that are duplicated, and I want to try to color each duplicate. Currently, when it does run it only goes to record # 107-109. I have 779 records with the possibility of more.

Is there a better way to identify duplicates without Conditional Formatting? I don't want to key 800+ entries and Google keeps telling me that's the way to go.

IE

```
1Z*5952 Red
1Z*5952 Red
1Z*5961 Blue
1Z*5961 Blue
1Z*5970 Green
1Z*5970 Green
1Z*5989 etc
```

Asterisk is omitting sensitive data, tracking numbers are 13 characters in length.

```
Sub ColourDuplicates()
Dim Rng As Range
Dim Cel As Range
Dim Cel2 As Range
Dim Colour As Long




Set Rng = Worksheets("Adj").Range("A2:A779" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
Rng.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
Colour = 1
For Each Cel In Rng


If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rng, Cel) > 1 And Cel.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone Then
Set Cel2 = Rng.Find(Cel.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
    If Not Cel2 Is Nothing Then
        Firstaddress = Cel2.Address
        Do
        Cel.Interior.Color = Colour
        Cel2.Interior.Color = Colour
            Set Cel2 = Rng.FindNext(Cel2)

        Loop While Firstaddress <> Cel2.Address
    End If




Colour = Colour + 1


End If
Next


End Sub
```

Comment: `Range("A2:A779" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)` - if you have 779 rows this equates to `Range("A2:A779779")` Plus you are missing a sheet reference.

Comment: ColorIndex only goes to 56, once ```colour``` gets to 57 it will give runtime error 9. You will need to either reset it and reuse colors or use ```rgb()```, though either way you are going to run out of colors different enough to tell at a glance.

Comment: Once you've colour coded the duplicates, what is it you want to do with them? There may be another way to accomplish your final goal.

Comment: I would eventually be adding the amounts owed for each duplicate package.